# Forcing VS 2010 to use over 2 GB of memory on 64 bit machines

Tags: visual-studio-2010

On a weblog I saw that we can Patch the devenv.exe to support 2+ GB memory, the problem is that for me it says editbin command is not found. so I am not sure what am I missing. 
I have Win7 64 bit and VS 2010 and I have only installed C# and not C++ .

here is the weblog: http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/04/29/hacking-visual-studio-to-use-more-than-2gigabytes-of-memory.aspx

and here is the command it says we should run:

```
 editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE devenv.exe
```

Has anybody done this before?

Comment: Link changed slightly, now it's http://old.stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/04/29/hacking-visual-studio-to-use-more-than-2gigabytes-of-memory.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's EDITBIN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd3shwhf.aspx) the command can only be run from within Visual Studio itself. You'll have to make a copy of devenv.exe to work against. I don't know why it would have this limitation, since it appears earlier versions did not.

> Note
>
> You can start this tool only from the Visual Studio command
> prompt. You cannot start it from a system command prompt or from
> Windows Explorer.